# Rails array help selecting column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this array:

```
[:dk, #<Domain dk: 8, id: 12, se: 5, com: 5>]
```

I want to select the dk: **8**?

So that the input is: 8

My view:

```
<% @prices.each do |price| %>
<%= price %><br />
<% end %>
```

The output:

```
[:dk, #<Domain dk: 8, id: 12, se: 5, com: 5>]
[:com, #<Domain dk: 8, id: 12, se: 5, com: 5>]
```

My controller:

```
def domain
  country_codes = %w[ dk com ]

  @domain = "asdsad"

  @results = { }
  @prices = { }

  country_codes.each do |cc|
    @results[cc] = Whois.whois("#{@domain}.#{cc}")
    @prices[cc.to_sym] = Domain.order(cc).first
  end
  render :layout => false
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have an Array, you have a Hash.

Do this:

```
<% @prices.each do |cc,domain| %>
  <%= domain.send(cc) %><br />
<% end %>
```

So:

- first: `#<Domain dk: 8, id: 12, se: 5, com: 5>.send(:dk) # => 8`
- second: `#<Domain dk: 8, id: 12, se: 5, com: 5>.send(:com) # => 5`

---

Upon request, further explanation.

- you create a Hash: `@prices = { }`
- then you fill it: `@prices[cc.to_sym] = Domain.order(cc).first`

The latest means to you add to the hash one object: `Domain.order(cc).first`, with it's key: `cc.to_sym`